# Ajax's Partial Response is giving view id could not be restored

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, tomcat7

I am using below configuration in project.

javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE Development javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD client but sometime it gives view could not be restored in ajax's partial response.
for example:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <error>  
     <error-name>
          class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
     </error-name>
     <error-message>
       <![CDATA[viewId:/workbench.xhtml - View /workbench.xhtml could not be restored.]]>
     </error-message>
    </error>
</partial-response>
```

Sometime no command button is working and there is no nested form. it was working fine almost 2 year now irregular of time it is giving this error after checking with firebug on client's system. sometime it gives 302,304 status for resources. It is very big project and single web application for the country and lots of concurrent user working.

Please help we are unable to solve the issue because it is not coming on when we do debugging on our end.

Comment: What changed? New server? Growth in users? Something else?

Comment: Growth in users is everyday.We are using clustering of apache web server with tomcat.Problem is coming on particular form which is very large in no of components and including many forms using manged property and including by ui:include tag

Comment: Did you turn on debugging to see if e.g. views are dropped because there are too many simultaneous views?

Comment: @Kulkeltje....How to see if the view is dropped or not at the time of debugging?

Comment: By the fact that there is a line in the debug logging that states so?

Comment: please help. No solution is found till the date.

Comment: Did you turn on debugging to see if e.g. views are dropped because there are too many simultaneous views?